# Положение мыши внутри autoscaled SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Я пытаюсь решить проблемы относительно положения курсора мыши внутри моего документа SVG.  Я бы хотел создать потенциометр, который будет следовать за курсором при перетаскивании, используя `JavaScript` на странице `HTML`.

Я пробовал `evt.clientX / Y` и`evt.screenX / Y`, но поскольку мой SVG находится в автомасштабировании, координаты внутри моего SVG отличаются.

Я искал ответ в течение нескольких дней, но я не мог найти решение (либо зная мой коэффициент масштабирования SVG в реальном времени, либо функцию для размещения мыши в системе координат SVG)

Вращение будет следовать простому правилу:

> if ( evt.screenX < xc) ang = Math.atan( (evt.screenY -
>   yc)/(evt.screenX - xc) )*360/(2*Math.PI) - 90; if( evt.screenX > xc )
>   ang = Math.atan( (evt.screenY - yc)/(evt.screenX - xc)
>   )*360/(2*Math.PI) + 90;

`(xc; yc)`,- как центр вращения и заменяя все `evt.screenX / Y` координатами мыши внутри моего SVG.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/10298658/7394871

Answer (score 3):

См. Этот код, который не только показывает, как преобразовать из пространства экрана в глобальное пространство SVG, но и как преобразовать точку из пространства SVG в преобразованное пространство элемента:
http://phrogz.net/svg/drag_under_transformation.xhtml

Вкратце:

```
// Находим root SVG элемента
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');

// Создаем SVGPoint для будущей математики
var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();

// Получаем точку в глобальном пространстве SVG
function cursorPoint(evt){
  pt.x = evt.clientX; pt.y = evt.clientY;
  return pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
}

svg.addEventListener('mousemove',function(evt){
  var loc = cursorPoint(evt);
  // Use loc.x and loc.y here
},false);
```

Я создал образец, соответствующий вашим потребностям (хотя и только в глобальном пространстве SVG)

это добавляет следующий метод:

```
function rotateElement(el,originX,originY,towardsX,towardsY){
  var angle = Math.atan2(towardsY-originY,towardsX-originX);
  var degrees = angle*180/Math.PI + 90;
  el.setAttribute(
    'transform',
    'translate('+originX+','+originY+') ' +
      'rotate('+degrees+') ' +
      'translate('+(-originX)+','+(-originY)+')'
  );
}
```

[**Рабочий пример**](http://phrogz.net/svg/rotate-to-point-at-cursor.svg)